# PHP download file while reading

Tags: php, linux, apache, synchronization

I have two PHP services.
One that let other users to download a file.
Another that fetch every some time an updated version of that file.
Now I am implementing it through flock().
I thought of improving it by using link() - I mean downloading the file and then link to the new downloaded file. But, there is a problem with this way because you cannot link() a file that is already is being link.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the new file to a temporary filename and then move it over to the real filename. No need to deal with links or locks. Your filesystem normally knows what it does.

Just add some error checking and deal with errors.

Comment: This is not a good solution because. What happen if while I am reading the file with the second process I am writing the file with the other. I don't think the move is an atomic action. am I right?

Comment: @Ben Laniado: This depends how the underlying file-system deals with that situation. [rename()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rename) itself is atomic if it's about one file, and the old as well as the new name is located on the same file-system. And using a PHP command - regardless if you rename a file or remove / recreate a link - always needs you to deal with the errors in any case.